# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tostring'

Tags: python, python-requests, python-imaging-library

Trying to convert image to string....

```
import requests
image = requests.get(image_url).content
image.tostring()
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tostring'

How do I turn this into something that Python understands as an image which I can then call tostring() on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.content` attribute of a response is *already a string*. Python string objects do not have a `tostring()` method.

Pillow / PIL in not coming into play here; the `requests` library does not return a Python Image Library object when loading an image URL. If you expected to have an `Image` object, you'll need to create that from the loaded data:

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import requests

image_data = BytesIO(requests.get(image_url).content)
image_obj = Image.open(image_data)
```

`image_obj` then is a PIL `Image` instance, and now you can convert that to raw image data with `Image.tostring()`:

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> import requests
>>> image_url = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/24780fb6df85a943c7aea0402c843737?s=128'
>>> image_data = BytesIO(requests.get(image_url).content)
>>> image_obj = Image.open(image_data)
>>> raw_image_data = image_obj.tostring()
>>> len(raw_image_data)
49152
>>> image_obj.size
(128, 128)
>>> 128 * 128 * 3
49152
```

Comment: Hi, So would it be possible to turn this into a Python image object and call tostring() on the actual image?