# Get binary image data in Python

Tags: python

How do I take an image and turn that into binary image data?

This is what I have tried:

```
class get_binary_data(image_url):

    #Get the image online online_image = http://www.myimg.com/test.jpg
    online_image = requests.get(image_url).content
    image_data = BytesIO(online_image)
```

However this does not seem to give me the binary image data, could someone help explain the process of getting the binary image data?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
 app = subprocess.Popen("externalApp",
                            in=subprocess.PIPE,
                            out=subprocess.PIPE)
    app.in.write(image_data)
    app.in.close()
```

which gives me the error:

IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: Why do you think `.content` isn't the binary image data? What is it instead? What are you doing with `image_data` that's giving you the error message? Don't show us an error message without the code that produced it.

Comment: @Wooble the error I get I will add to OP now

Comment: @Wooble are you saying requests.get(image_url).content is the binary data?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to wrap the response data in a `BytesIO` object just to write it to a pipe. Use the `response.content` data *directly*:

```
class get_binary_data(image_url):
    #Get the image online online_image = http://www.myimg.com/test.jpg
    return requests.get(image_url).content
```

I used a `BytesIO` object in my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25341130) only because you wanted to load that data into a PIL `Image` object. It is a requirement for `Image.open()` that a file-like object with seek support is provided, and `BytesIO` does just that.

Here, however, you need a (byte)string, so just use the `.contents` value.