# Convert from string to bytes without changing the data in Python 3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I would like to download binary data (a `.wav` file) from a website using python 3.

I was able to get the binary data as a string using `requests.get` but when I tried to write it to a file, the data was changed and the saved file was not correct:

```
import requets
waveurl = 'http://www ..... /song.wav'
res = requests.get(waveurl)
with open("song.wav, "wb") as f:
    f.write(bytes(res.text)
```

I also tried using `struct.pack("B",each_byte)` but it didn't help.

How can I convert properly download and save binary data to a file without changing it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25341714/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Request documentation you can access the [response body as bytes](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) using content instead of text. I would recommend that you give that a try.

```
import request
waveurl = 'http://www ..... /song.wav'
res = requests.get(waveurl)
with open("song.wav, "wb") as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

I haven't tested this option, this i meant to provide a starting point for you.

Comment: thx it solved it yeeey  Thx....  but ....  still how to take string and chage his meaning as bytes without changes

Comment: In your case I would recommend getting the raw bytes, since converting a string to bytes would require you to know the char set. Here is another thread that may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3. And since it is a related topic you may also want to look into character sets since that is an important part of converting text to bytes https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: Also, since this solved your question please do consider accepting the answer.